# How do I make auto generate id with unique random order?

Tags: mysql

How do I make auto generated id with unique random order. Is it possible ? I need my output shows like whenever new row added id field shows random numbers not in sequence order. How can I modify this script.

Script:

```
    CREATE TABLE `student`.`new_table` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Comment: please frame your question in good way add some instances, add table structure etc

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this what you want:

```
UUID_SHORT()    Return an integer-valued universal identifier
UUID()          Return a Universal Unique Identifier (UUID)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html